Android emulator and frame-ancestors policy issue
I have flutter app with InAppWebView in my  which is running on my android emulator. This InAppWebView containing iframe with third party widget, which throws an error on loading
Refused to frame 'https://mock.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://localhost:8080"

From my understanding its because android emulator using 10.0.2.2:8080 instead of localhost:8080 because this frame is working in web and ios versions of application without problems. Is there a way to replace android emulator's 10.0.2.2:8080 with localhost:8080 so it behaves as a real device?
